# Button in Modal Popup Is not working as it should have to worked

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, authentication

I am Having a code for Modal PopUp windoe in which I wanna perform login operation and code for extender is as follows.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul id="icons">
<li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="images/lgn.png" ID="btnimg" CssClass="image" /></a></li>
</ul>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnimg" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender >
<asp:panel id="Panel1" CssClass="popup" runat="server">
<div class="popup">
<div id="PopupHeader" style="height:55px;background-color:#f6f6f6;border-radius:10px;width:348px;font-size:2.7em; "> <font style="margin:30px 0px 0px 20px;vertical-align:middle;color:Black;line-height:1.2em; font-size:37px; font-family: BonvenoCF;"> Login         </font></div>
<div class="PopupBody">
<table width="350px" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp; </td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name: "></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Height="20px" style="border-radius:8px;">   </asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtUserName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"  Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtUserName"WatermarkText="User Name">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password: " ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="width:131.25px">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Height="20px" style="border-radius:8px;">  </asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtPassword_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPassword" 
                        WatermarkText="Password">
</asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Invalid User Name Or Password." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="width:43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login" />
</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancle" /></td>
<td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Forgot Password</asp:LinkButton>
</td>
<td style="width: 131.25px">
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Sign Up" />
</td>
<td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</asp:panel>
</div>
```

on `button2_Click` code behind is as follows.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = obj.sel("select UserName and Password from tblUserMaster where UserName='"+txtUserName.Text+"' AND Password='"+txtPassword.Text+"'");

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        Label3.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

But when i'm clicking on LOGIN Button it is not redirection me on Default.aspx page popup is getting closed.
while on clicking on cancel button it is not working at all.

please suggest an solution as soon as possible.

Comment: what you have edited can you tel me sir..??
i don't got it so...

Comment: You must be getting exception, please debug you code.

Comment: i am not getting any exceptions even... :( :(
Actually my Buttonclick event is not hapening and i don't know anything about solution :o :(

Comment: did you tried to keep your code in try and used catch block and debugged ? try using it.

Comment: but sir i've putted breakpoint on buttonclick and when i've clciked on button nthing happened..

Comment: Just write 4 line of code bro. Sometime Response.Redirect throws exception which can't be caught without try catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use update panel for refreshing problem .
here is complete code .

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <div class="wrapper">
<ul id="icons">
<li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="images/lgn.png" ID="btnimg" CssClass="image" /></a></li>
</ul>
       <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnimg" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="Button1"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="popup" runat="server">
           <div class="popup">
               <div id="PopupHeader" style="height: 55px; background-color: #f6f6f6; border-radius: 10px; width: 348px; font-size: 2.7em;"><font style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 20px; vertical-align: middle; color: Black; line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 37px; font-family: BonvenoCF;"> Login         </font></div>
               <div class="PopupBody">
                   <table width="350px" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp; </td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name: "></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Height="20px" Style="border-radius: 8px;">   </asp:TextBox>

                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Height="20px" Style="border-radius: 8px;">  </asp:TextBox>
                               <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtPassword_TextBoxWatermarkExtender"
                                   runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPassword"
                                   WatermarkText="Password">
                               </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td colspan="2">
                               <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Invalid User Name Or Password." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Cancle" /></td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Forgot Password</asp:LinkButton>
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 131.25px">
                               <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
                           </td>
                           <td style="width: 43.5px">&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </asp:Panel>
           </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chirag : you haven't added the onclick event on your button . so please add this .. 
edit your code .

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Login" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
```

Comment: well spotted! all of us keep looking for some complex solution that we forgot about the basics...

Comment: still not working...
as your answer is helpfull @Amit Kumar but whel i'm clicking on button2 page is getting reloaded i want to avoid that reloading what todo for that.?

Comment: for working of cancel button , you have to add another property , to modelpop up 
CancelControlID="Button1"

Comment: of course page will reload, as you redirecting to another page on button click. but you can do one thing . 
put you panel inside 
update panel control.

Comment: but sir if i put code inside update pannel then after clicking on submit button popup changes it's place on page and my design of whole page is getting disturbed.

Comment: after clicking on submit button . write your all code , whatever you want to do to then at the end of all , write this line 
ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
hope this will help you .